# Montando url para teste no cUrl

Tags: android, http, libcurl, retrofit

Estou utilizando Retrofit para chamar uma API interna de um site que estou testando.
Uma url parecida com a que possuo é esta: `www.sitedeteste.com/r/`

Em meu retrofit do Android tenho essa declaração do PUT:

```
@PUT("/ordem/{Id}/{tipo}")
```

Em meu terminal Ubuntu minha url com cUrl é essa:

```
curl -v -X PUT "http://www.sitedeteste.com/r/ordem/1/TO GO"
```

E tentei de outras formas como:

```
curl -v -X PUT -d "Id=1&tipo=TO GO" http://www.sitedeteste.com/r/ordem/1/TO GO
```

Mas não estou tendo sucesso no teste. O erro sempre é esse:

```
* Connected to sitedeteste.com (---.---.---.---) port 80 (#0)
> PUT /r/ordem/1/TO GO HTTP/1.1
> Host: sitedeteste.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.50.1
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
* no chunk, no close, no size. Assume close to signal end
< 
* Closing connection 0
```

Não sei mais o que fazer para testar? Estou errando em algum ponto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creio que tenha que mudar os espaço para o sinal de `+` ou `%20`, ou seja entre os `/` você deve codificar, faça assim:

```
curl -v -X PUT -d "Id=1&tipo=TO%20GO" "http://www.sitedeteste.com/r/ordem/1/TO%20GO"
```

Ou assim:

```
curl -v -X PUT -d "Id=1&tipo=TO+GO" "http://www.sitedeteste.com/r/ordem/1/TO+GO"
```